# Azuma's Inequality when the conditions hold with high probability?

Tags: measure-concentration, pr.probability, probability-distributions, co.combinatorics

In Azuma's Inequality, is the statement true when $|X_k - X_{k-1}| < c_k$ almost surely rather than with probability 1? If not, is there another result which gives strong concentration when the above inequality (for each $k$) holds with high probability?

Comment: Do you mean almost surely vs. surely?  Almost surely implies probability 1...

Comment: Yes, I mean almost surely instead of surely.

Comment: What do you mean by high probability? Do you just want $|X_k - X_{k-1}|< c_{k}$ to hold with probability tending to $1$, as $k \to \infty$? I guess, that when this convergence is fast enough, then some sort of Azuma's inequality still holds, but only for tails distant enough and, of course, with worse constants. I haven't thought about it too long, so I may be wrong.

Comment: If the martingales considered is $(X_k)_{k=1}^{N}$, what I mean is that $\mathbb{P}(\forall k, |X_k - X_{k-1}| < c_k) \to 1$ as $N$ goes to $\infty$.

Comment: But this sequence of probabilities is clearly nonincreasing, so it has to be constantly equal to 1; thus, assumptions of Azuma's inequality are satisfied.

Comment: The sequence is not necessarily non-increasing as for two distinct values of $N$ and fixed $k$, $P(|X_k - X_{k-1}|)$ is not necessarily equal.

Comment: @Patt: As fuzzytron says, "almost surely" means with probability equal to 1.  You apparently mean what people sometimes call "asymptotically almost surely".  I doubt there is a nice result under such a weak assumption as you stated in the comment above.  If you don't really need the martingale structure, Hoeffding's inequality for *independent* random variables extends to a subgaussian tail condition.

Comment: The absolute values $|d_k|$ of the martingale differences can have any joint distribution subject to the boundedness constraint, so you can make the exceptional sets disjoint for a long time and $|d_k|$ large on the $k$-th exceptional set $A_k$.  Piecing things together, you get a counterexample if $\Bbb{P}(A_k)\to 0$ but is not summable.

Comment: Can someone please tell me the statement of azuma inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a large literature on variations of Azuma's inequality. One lemma that is similar to what you ask is Lemma 3.1 of [this old paper of Wormald and myself](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/degseq1.pdf). It considers the case where $|X_k-X_{k-1}|$ is within one bound with very high probability and within some wider bound always. There are lots of such results.